# Python Selenium not clicking Link?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, click, href

I am getting a list of links that I want to click. I get the href of each of them and I am able to locate the element using it, but when I try to click it, it just appears as if I were hovering on top of it.

The list is called links and the href that I am trying to access is links[1]

I have alredy tried normally clicking it:

```
   self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[contains(@href,links[1])]').click()
```

And double clicking it:

```
    actionChains = ActionChains(self.driver)
    a=self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[contains(@href,links[1])]')
    actionChains.double_click(a).perform()
```

But the behaviour is as if I only put the cursor on top of the link without clicking it.

Answer (score 1):

just fix the xpath

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[contains(@href,'{}')]".format(links[1])).click()
```

or if you prefer ActionChains

```
actionChains = ActionChains(self.driver)
a=self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//*[contains(@href,'{}')]".format(links[1]))
actionChains.double_click(a).perform()
```